# Bad HTML in flag overlay

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

There's an extra `</a>` in the flag overlay shown when viewing the full flagged post:

[image: screenshot]

It's escaped in the source:

```
<a class="flagged-post-link" href="#54992">answered&lt;/a&gt; <span title="2015-02-21 16:40:36Z" class="relativetime">5 hours ago</span> by </a>
```

Comment: I was just coming here to post about it.

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh, it's an *apron*! Thanks!